# Would the player be fined after getting convicted for fake injury?

Tags: rules, football, injuries

I have come across this gif on Facebook, where the goal-keeper of the opposite team disproves the injury of a player (I'm not sure about what match it was).

> [image]

So, **would players who get disproved of injury be fined?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disciplinary action has certainly been taken over players who have been shown to feign injury. One of the most infamous instances of this was at the 2002 FIFA World Cup; during a group match between Brazil and Turkey, when Rivaldo went down covering his face after being struck on the hip by a ball kicked at him by a Turkish player. The referee sent off the Turkish player for a second yellow-card offence, but upon video review – which clearly proved the Brazilian’s cheating intent – Rivaldo was [fined by FIFA](http://news.bbc.co.uk/sport3/worldcup2002/hi/matches_wallchart/brazil_v_turkey/newsid_2023000/2023985.stm).

In 1989, a match between Brazil and Chile was abandoned after the Chilean goalkeeper Roberto Rojas appeared to be injured by a flare thrown onto the pitch by a spectator. The [1989 World Cup qualifying incident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roberto_Rojas#1989_World_Cup_qualifying_incident) resulted in more than just the play-acting player being punished.

> Video evidence later showed that Rojas had not been hit by the firework. His head injury was discovered to have been self-inflicted with a razor blade hidden in his glove. FIFA awarded Brazil a 2-0 win, effectively eliminating Chile from the 1990 World Cup. As a consequence, Chile was banned from the 1994 FIFA World Cup and Rojas was banned for life, along with the coach Orlando Aravena and the team doctor Daniel Rodriguez.